# perl regex to replicate split

Tags: regex, perl, split

I am able to get all words in a file using split() however when I tried with regex it is not returning the same words as in split() returns

What is wrong with my regex?

```
undef $/;
my $string = <DATA>;

print "---  Split  ---\n";
my @split = split(/\s+/,$string); # return all words
print "---  Regex ---\n";    
my @word_found = $string =~ m/\s+\w+\s+/smg; # this regex is not returning the same words

__DATA__
Hi,
Perl is regular expression is ....
1+1=2
().()
m == m
m=1+k;
m++;

Regards,
*  WARNING: This is a string:                      *
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\w` matches *word* characters `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.  Your regex uses that and requires those word characters be flanked by one or more whitespace characters.  Note that `Hi` at the beginning of your string wouldn't be a match, since there are no leading whitespace characters.

The following will produce the same results as your use of `split`:

```
my @word_found = $string =~ /\S+/g;
```

Be sure to first implement the DATA slurping change suggested by [sateesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58220/sateesh).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks it it working now!!
Do you mind to explain why the above returns only
    `Perl   regular   is`
    `m   m`
    `This   a`
Why did the my regex ignore the "is" ,"regular" and "...." in the line "Perl is regular expression is"?

Comment: @user2763829 - Glad it's working for your now.  Note that the words your regex matched are surrounded by at least one whitespace.  When it matched `Perl` it was `\nPerl\s+`, so all whitespaces after `Perl` are used, leaving none for `\s+is\s+`, so it's skipped.  The next word surrounded by whitespaces is `regular`.  Notice that there are two spaces between these words: `\s+Perl\s+\s+regular\s+`  The `....` are ignored, since they do not match `\w+`, as it's equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]+`.

Comment: I have more understanding on how regex works now.. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are slurping the **DATA** section incorrectly. You just need to do:

```
my $string =<DATA>
```

and the regex can be, capture any non-space characters:

```
my @word_found = $string =~ m/([^\s]+)/smg;
```